# How to change a cod from FOR to WHILE? (code in the body)

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, while-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a code that search into 2 chains, and give the bigest chain we can get from the both of them, print it and get how mane characters it have.

example: if i put 'paris' and 'sarix', we will get ari=3

Now, i need to know how to do it in while or other loops, but i really don't know how to do it, so if you could help me i would apreciate it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE calc_cadena AS 
    FUNCTION FNC_CALCULASUB (cadena1 VARCHAR2, cadena2 VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN varchar2; 
END; 

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY calc_cadena AS 
    var_ejemplo number; 
    FUNCTION FNC_CALCULASUB (cadena1 VARCHAR2, cadena2 VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN varchar2 
    IS 
    caden varchar2(1000);   
    conta number(5);       
    BEGIN 
         conta:=0;  
         caden:='';  
         for I in 1..length(cadena2) loop 
             for J in I..length(cadena2) loop 
                 if UPPER(instr(cadena1,substr(cadena2,I,J-I+1)))>0 then 
                    if length(substr(cadena2,I,J-I+1))>conta then     
                        conta:=length(substr(cadena2,I,J-I+1));     
                        caden:=substr(cadena2,I,J-I+1);             
                    end if;
                 end if;
             end loop;
         end loop;

        return caden||'='||to_char(length(caden)); 
    end; 
end;  

SELECT calc_cadena.FNC_CALCULASUB('paris','sarix')
FROM    DUAL;
```

trying my best btw.

Comment: If you have something that works, why do you need to change it?

Comment: @AlexPoole to learn, if you know how to do it, it would be awesome if you share your knowledge. :D